# whether + infinitive

Tags: conditional-constructions, infinitives

I am not sure how the construction "whether + [infinitive verb]" is used. Examples:

- I don't know whether to turn left or right. (= I don't know if I turn left or right ?)
- I don't know whether to turn left will take us to the hotel. (= I don't know if turning left will take us to the hotel )

Are these two sentences gramatically correct? Do they have the meaning inside the parentheses?

Comment: Your second example is a problem. To be consistent with your first example, it should be:  "I don't know whether to turn left to take us to the hotel". (You could also say "I don't know whether turning left will take us to the hotel.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Original A**: I don't know whether to turn left or right. (= I don't know if I turn left or right ?)

The first version is fine. There needs to be a "should" in the parenthesis version.

> I don't know if I *should* turn left or right.

Yes, they mean the same thing. Note that there are only two options here, you either go left or right (in B you have three options).

> **Original B**: I don't know whether to turn left will take us to the hotel. (= I don't know if turning left will take us to the hotel )

Note that if you just write left (instead or "left OR right") then you are saying "... should I turn left, right, or keep going straight... (unless there is no straight path and the road splits in opposite directions).

The following is how I would say it (BillJ in his comment says the same thing).

> I don't know whether to turn left **to** get to the hotel. OR, I don't know whether turning left will get us to the hotel.

Comment: Adding a "should" to the 1st sentence makes sense indeed. My sentence was a bad literal translation from my native tongue (Portuguese). Regarding the 2nd sentence, I didn't know that only infinitives were allowed after using whether + infinitive verb. Thanks!